# php regex white space ignore quotes

Tags: php, regex, string

Using php and regex, I need to split up a string of data into pieces with the following requirements.

1. Split it on white space
2. Ignore whitespace within quotes.

For example:

1. $string='tid:1212121'; - should just return a single array with "tid:1212121"
2. $string='tid:1211 topic:ted title:"This Title"'; should return an array with 
   3 pieces tid:1211, topic:ted and title:"This Title".

I've looked around but my personal regex capabilities are horrible. Also I cannot control the input so the quotes will not be escaped. The string will be as quoted above or longer such as $string='tid:1211 topic:ted title:"This Title" lid:332 fid:"another bit of text"';

Thank you!

Comment: I see no whitespace in `$string='tid:1212121';`. Are you trying to parse PHP files?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Not php files, just input. It needs to be able to parse both. So sometimes the input has a space and sometimes the input is just on value.

Answer (score 0):

If every quoted is preceded by non space characters this could help you:

```
preg_match_all('/([^ ]*("[^"]*")[\s])|([^ ]+[\s])/', $string, $matches);
```

You can see in action at : [phpliveregex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/go5) and selecting preg_match_all

Comment: Thank You for this.

Comment: I tested this with a smaller values and it doesn't work. I'll see what else I can come up with.

I tried 'pid:354 title:joe'